# C# Odata WebApi concurrency with byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have set up a WebApi endpoint for OData V4. I am not using an entity framework directly instead i have defined some POCO's.

```
public class ServiceDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

My Problem is in Patch method of the Odata Controller i will check the If-Match header Like:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] string key, Delta<ServiceDTO> patch, ODataQueryOptions<ServiceDTO> options)
    {
        if (patch == null)
        {
            var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            responseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed;
            responseMessage.Content = new StringContent("Missing properties");
            return ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
        }

        Validate(patch.GetEntity());

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (options.IfMatch != null)
        {
            var result = this.repository.Get(options).AsQueryable().Where(u => u.Id == key);
            if (!result.Any())
            {
                // The entity doesn't exist on the database and as the request contains an If-Match header we don't
                // insert the entity instead (No UPSERT behavior if the If-Match header is present).
                return NotFound();
            }
            else if (!((IQueryable<ServiceDTO>)options.IfMatch.ApplyTo(result)).Any())
            {
                // The ETag of the entity doesn't match the value sent on the If-Match header, so the entity has
                // been modified by a third party between the entity retrieval and update..
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed);
            }
            else
            {
                // The entity exists in the database and the ETag of the entity matches the value on the If-Match 
                // header, so we update the entity.
                var service = await this.repository.Get(key);
                patch.Patch(service);
                await this.repository.Update(service);
                if (service == null)
                    return BadRequest();
                return Ok(service);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            responseMessage.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)428;
            return ResponseMessage(responseMessage);
        }
    }
```

Using a byte[] in POCO i will always end up with Precondition failed. When i replace the data type from byte[] to string or int64 all works ok.

I also tried replacing the DataAnnotation from [Timestamp] to [ConcurrencyCheck] but this has no effect.

We had this code working before in another project with byte but we were using directly EF.

The repository is resolved at runtime and it can be either a repository that works with EF or another custom one that works with a different back-end.

I tested with an EF repository and an In-memory repository.